# GNU Radio Companion WX Instrumentation

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

**GNU Radio Companion 3.7.9**

I've been looking and trying to fix my problem for 2 days on 2 different Linux systems (both Debian) Currently I am on Ubuntu 16.04.
When I open GNU Radio Companion and grab a any WX GUI (for example: WX GUI FFT Sink) from the Instrumentation stack I always get the following error:

> Can't generate this block in mode 'qt_gui'.

And if I click "View Flow Graphs Errors" it always says:

> Block - wxgui_fftsink2_0 - WX GUI FFT Sink(wxgui_fftsink2): Can't generate this block in mode 'qt_gui'.

I've tried installing pretty much all dependencies I've came across on the Internet, and I don't even know what else. It happens also on my Kali linux Machine. I am using HackRF One. Everything else seems to be working fine besides this. If I run the command **osmocom_fft** I get working graph with signals. That means I cannot execute the flow graph at all.

Answer (score 9):

The error says what the problem is. In the "Options" Block, switch from Qt to wx. Problem solved.

Better yet, replace your wx widgets with the equivalent qt ones - the WX codebase has effectively gone unmaintained for years now, and we've removed the WX library from the current GNU Radio release, so don't design new flow graphs using WX, even if you're using the legacy GNU Radio 3.7.

I repeat: **Do not use WX GUI for new GNU Radio applications**.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it. The reason I use WX is that I was following some tutorials from the Greatscott gadgets website

Comment: these should work if you really just replace the WX widgets with the same Qt ones (what's –less than luckily– named "WX FFT sink" is equivalent to the "Qt Freq Sink", the rest should practically have the same name). The Qt things are generally faster. Try the menu that you get when clicking on the plot with the middle mouse button!

Comment: @MarcusMüller, but what is the QT's alternative for WX Scope Sink? I would like to change seconds and counts per division but was not able to do that with QT.

Comment: Time sink. You can set the unit to "counts", if I remember correctly. If you can't: on github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/issues file an issue that this wx functionality is missing from qt